# Transforming an R table avoiding duplicates

Tags: r

i have a list of genes with an attribute associated in a 2 column table. What i want is to transform this table:

```
Gene    person
TMCS09g1008676  mathias
TMCS09g1008677  leonard
TMCS09g1008678  marcus
TMCS09g1008679  jan
TMCS09g1008680  jose
TMCS09g1008676  jose
TMCS09g1008677  marcus
```

in this:

```
Gene    person
TMCS09g1008676  mathias_jose
TMCS09g1008677  leonard_marcus
TMCS09g1008678  marcus
TMCS09g1008679  jan
TMCS09g1008680  jose
```

Someone knows a way to do it in R?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

We can do a group by paste

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Gene) %>%
   summarise(person = paste(person, collapse="_"))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(person ~ Gene, df1, paste, collapse='_')
```